# Upper and lower bound of $L_2$ norm of $\lVert A x \rVert_{2}$, where $A \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $x \in M_{n,1}(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am sorry for asking a (trivial)  question which might have been raised Before. But I could not find it with simple search. Perhaps, it is well-known (?)

> Do we have an upper and lower (preferably tight) bound of an $L_2$ norm of a matrix-vector product $\lVert A x \rVert_{2}$, where $A \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $x \in M_{n,1}(\mathbb{C})$?

---

partial attempt

\begin{align}
 \alpha \ \lVert x \rVert_{2} \leq \lVert A x \rVert_{2} \leq \underbrace{\beta}_{\lVert A\rVert_{F} \ ?} \ \lVert x \rVert_{2} \ .
\end{align}

- Is $\beta = \lVert A\rVert_{F}$  (Frobenius norm of $A$)? If yes, which theorem applies?
- What would be an appropriate $\alpha$?

Comment: The left hand in equality cannot hold unless $A$ has trivial kernel.

Comment: The tightest $\beta$ would be the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^*A$. If $\alpha$ exists the tightest value is the square root of the smallest eigenvalue of $A^*A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @logarithm points out in comments, the tight bounds come from the spectrum of $A^\star A$. Indeed, writing $\|Ax\|^2=\langle Ax|Ax\rangle=\langle A^\star A x| x\rangle$, we see that 
$$
\begin{array}{cc}\displaystyle 
   \sup_{x\ne 0} \frac{\|Ax\|^2}{\|x\|^2}=\max \sigma (A^\star A), & \displaystyle \inf_{x\ne 0} \frac{\|Ax\|^2}{\|x\|^2}=\min \sigma (A^\star A),
\end{array}
$$
where $\sigma(A^\star A)$ is the set of all eigenvalues of $A^\star A$. Note that such eigenvalues are nonnegative, because $A^\star A$ is semidefinite positive.

In practice, computing these eigenvalues can be difficult. The Frobenius norm is a much simpler object, and it provides an upper bound, which, however, is not sharp. To see this, note that 
$$
\|Ax\|^2=\sum_i\left\lvert \sum_j a_{ij}x_j\right\rvert^2 \le \sum_i(\sum_j |a_{ij}|^2 \sum_j |x_j|^2)=\|A\|_F^2 \|x\|^2, $$
where we used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.