# Lower bound of Euclidean norm for triangular matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Quick question based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226783/upper-and-lower-bound-of-l-2-norm-of-lvert-a-x-rvert-2-where-a-in-m) regarding the Euclidean norm of a matrix. In general we know that if $A$ is a square matrix then we have $$\lambda_m \|x\|_2^2 \leq \|Ax\|_2^2 \leq \lambda_M \|x\|_2^2,$$ where $\lambda_m = \min_{1 \leq i \leq n} \lambda_i(A^TA)$ and $\lambda_n = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \lambda_i(A^TA)$. These are the "sharpest" bounds, but computing them in general is difficult.

I am interested in the case where $A$ is a triangular matrix. Is there anything we can say in this case, specifically for the lower bound. What I mean, is that we can get an upper bound by using the Frobenius norm, but I am not sure about the lower bound. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To start with let's assume that $A$ is an invertible matrix, else the lower bound is just zero. Then a similarly weak lower bound is:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\left(\left\Vert A^{-1}\right\Vert ^{F}\right)^{2}}\leq min_{i\in\{1,...,n\}}\lambda_{i}\left(A^{T}A\right)
\end{align}

Generally $A^{-1}$ is not a straight forward calculation, but is
made somewhat more straight forward given that $A$ is a triangular
matrix.

Some working:

Let $\sigma_{1}(A)\geq\sigma_{2}(A)\geq...\geq\sigma_{n}(A)$, be
the singular values of $A$, and let $\lambda_{1}(A^{T}A)\geq\lambda_{2}(A^{T}A)\geq...\geq\lambda_{n}(A^{T}A)$.

(See: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular\_value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular%5C_value)
and [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular\_value\_decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular%5C_value%5C_decomposition))

We have that

\begin{align}
\sigma_{i}(A)^{2}=\lambda_{i}(A^{T}A)
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sigma_{min}(A)}=\sigma_{max}(A^{-1})\leq\left\Vert A^{-1}\right\Vert ^{F}
\end{align}

and so the inequality follows.

ALTERNATIVE BOUND

For a triangular matrix, the determinant is just the product of the
diagonal entries. Further

\begin{align}
det\left(A^{T}A\right)=det\left(A\right)^{2}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
det\left(A^{T}A\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}(A^{T}A)
\end{align}

Now, as $\left(\left\Vert A\right\Vert ^{F}\right)^{2}\geq\lambda_{1}(A^{T}A)$
then

\begin{align}
\lambda_{n}(A^{T}A)=\frac{det\left(A\right)^{2}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\lambda_{i}(A^{T}A)}\geq\frac{det\left(A\right)^{2}}{\left(\left\Vert A\right\Vert ^{F}\right)^{2\left(n-1\right)}}
\end{align}

This provides another lower bound, all be it a quite weak one. But
it does benefit from minimal additional calculation as that of the
upper bound using the Frobenius norm.